# SQL adds rows on top of eachother rather than aside

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the following tables;

```
PRICE_TABLE             FACT_TABLE
P_ID                    P_ID
1                       0    
2                       0
3                       0
...                     ....
```

I am trying to get the values of `PRICE_TABLE` `P_ID` into the `FACT_TABLE`. I have gone with using the following query;

```
INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE(P_ID) SELECT P_ID FROM PRICE_TABLE
```

I have several more similar fields in the `FACT_TABLE` corresponding to other tables ie. `SALES_TABLE` of which the `S_ID` would need to come over in the same manner.

However running the queries like so;

```
INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE(P_ID) SELECT P_ID FROM PRICE_TABLE

INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE(S_ID) SELECT S_ID FROM SALES_TABLE
```

Will add the second `INSERT` statement on top of the other, so the second IDs only start when the first set have finished.

eg.

```
FACT_TABLE
P_ID     S_ID
1        NULL
2        NULL
3        NULL
NULL     1
NULL     2
NULL     3
...      ...
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Just how are the rows supposed to know which goes with which?  SQL table does not have an inherent order.

Comment: INSERT statements always add new rows. I'm not sure from the description above what your expected behaviour is, but if you wanted to update the first lot of rows created with the P_IDs to have S_IDs as well, then you need to use UPDATE statements to update existing rows, rather than add new ones?

Comment: Is there any relation between the `PRICE_TABLE` and `SALES_TABLE` ?

Comment: Change the second INSERT to an UPDATE.

Comment: You need to insert them at the same time; `INSERT INTO fact_table (p_id, s_id)` and for that you need to join your input tables together `SELECT price_table.p_id, sales_table.s_id FROM price_table INNER JOIN sales_table ON ??????`.  Unfortunately, you have not given enough information to fill in what goes in place of the `??????`...

Comment: Apologies on the lack of information and the novice question, thanks for the suggestions. I will try the join approach. There is no relation between the two tables, they are dimension tables and I am trying to populate the fact table with the dimensions PKs. Thanks again all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them all
You cannot associate if there is nothing to base the association on

```
INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE (P_ID, S_ID) 
SELECT P_ID, S_ID
FROM       PRICE_TABLE 
CROSS JOIN SALES_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running two separate inserts. So the first one runs and populates P_ID and then the second runs and populates S_ID. You want to combine the two inserts into one.

---

```
INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE (P_ID, S_ID)
VALUES (pt.P_ID, st.S_ID)
FROM PRICE_TABLE pt
INNER JOIN SALES_TABLE st
on st.P_ID = pt.P_ID
```

---

The above is assuming PRICE_TABLE and SALES_TABLE have a common column (in this case P_ID). If they don't you'll need to give more info on what you're trying to accomplish (do you want every P_ID for every S_ID, do you only want when P_ID = S_ID, etc).

Comment: There is no relation between `PRICE` and `SALES`, each have their own unique IDs which I am trying to pull into the `FACT` table which at present is empty but I intend to populate it with said IDs from the tables.